# How to enable a button after having a text box score of 5?

Tags: c#

I am working on my school project but I can't debug my code. When the text box score reaches 5, I can't enable the average button from another panel.

I already tried the `if` loop when clicked all the right answers from the other panels.

```cs
private void Quizportion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txtScoreTab = "5")
        //(rbtnA1.Checked && rbtnC2.Checked && rbtnEasyA3.Checked && rbtnEasyA4.Checked && rbtnEasyD5.Checked){
        btnAverage.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

This will enable the "Average" button from another panel.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the incorrect event to check.
Look for the txtScoreTab_TextChanged event

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

But why were you trying to check on the text instead of the actual data?
Here's a solution to that problem.

```
private int counter_ = 0;
public int counter 
{
    get { return counter_; }
    set {
         //You don't have to worry about the variable 'value'. 
         if(value == 5) btnAverage.Enabled = true; // it checks if the value is 5
         txtScoreTab.Text = value.ToString(); //when the value of counter is updated, txtScoreTab.Text changes correspondingly.
         counter_ = value; // the value of counter updates here. 
    }
}
```

Here's the explanation:
When the counter is being updated, it will check if its value reaches 5, if yes, the button will then be enabled.
What you should do is to increment the counter on every updates.

Example

```
counter = 4; 
counter++; // At this point, the button will be enabled The text will be updated as well. You can also write counter += 1; as well
```

Implement the above code snippet into your code and you're good to go.